# How do I find the minimum gradient descent value and plot it against a number of cities

Tags: python, matplotlib

My cities coordinates are:

```
cities={(0.18968464793049278, 0.10340486358509036), (0.1354657585465711, 0.3208994186407226), (0.4235133437959014, 0.26836801419126105), (0.6887870778089015, -0.05030184385892021), (0.24537999875842617, 0.289832851648385), (0.8434100960493063, 0.4682517533670828), (0.5183002011348364, 0.1727641164802532), (0.4348857795043566, 0.14072683422977939), (0.5577521902256685, 0.017136278418132422), (0.7522516256009651, 0.7107359089046797), (0.6848862550087679, 0.6674696735673874), (0.3719599412763801, -0.07944336179017772), (0.293392484501665, -0.003171602841475954), (0.35752778535234075, 0.1598990210251617), (0.33491559341097554, 0.23591678310565742), (0.3971436822573087, 0.2515368984878056), (0.30433583590757174, 0.13339331418116038), (0.2116853755259368, 0.3854592996508687), (0.5668890902347636, 0.1366746845234751), (0.2835192084616323, 0.08433949022700254), (0.5720632080929219, -0.07821058853535133), (0.7696111324067614, 0.6522502449131826), (0.270530417351808, -0.23567578194668565), (0.23385682990830342, 0.10644249906497753)}
```

my airport coordinates are:

```
airport_coord=[(0.6630711391725644, 0.9690637051721871), (0.026626928285107376, 0.9737016600928531), (0.06584862825331073, 0.8483132602207636)]
```

my alpha value is:

```
alpha=0.01
```

and gradient is:

```
gradient_value=[(5.354066376686878, 206.65546066464867)]
```

I am trying to iterate to minimize the gradient value given by `airport_coord-=alpha*gradient` and plot the cities vs the new airport location

I tried this:

```
alpha=0.01
for i in range(len(airport_coord)):
    airport_coord[i] = (airport_coord[i][0] - alpha * gradient_value[0][0], airport_coord[i][1] - alpha * gradient_value[0][1])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zip_cities = zip(*cities)
plt.scatter(*zip_cities, marker='+',color='b', label='Cities')
airp=zip(*airport_coord)
plt.scatter(*airp, marker="*",color='r',label='Airports')
plt.legend()
plt
```

But I did not get the output of finding the minimum distance between the cities and airport coordinates nor did the plotting happen accurately. What should I do?